# Natural deduction proof for the following sequent?

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I cannot solve the following sequent using natural deduction:

∃x∀y P(x,y) ⊢ ∃y∀xP(x,y)

However the familiar example I have no issue in solving:

∃x∀y P(x,y) ⊢ ∀y∃xP(x,y)

I am not sure how it is a valid statement, as it seems to be suggesting that you can swap the positions of 2-place predicates?

Thanks

Comment: It is **not** valid; consider $\mathbb N$ and $∃x∀y (x \le y)$, which is *true*, and $∃y∀x(x \le y)$, which is *false*.

Comment: yep thanks! It must of been a typo on the question